# Function with generic list parameter? (Overloading function)

Tags: java, android

Objective: What I need is to create a function or functions to handle different types of `List` parameter, and I will be iterating through the list in the function.

Attempts:

1- Multiple functions with different type of List

```
public static int update(List<MyClass> myClasses){};
public static int update(List<Project> rojects){};
public static int update(List<Time> times){};
```

But that deemed to be in-compilable as due to multiple functions with same parameter type `List`.

2- Generic type of list, and using (`instanceof`) However, I failed to completely do this as I am not sure how, and as much as I read, this seems to be an unfavorable way of such action.

My question: what is the Java way of implementing such requirement? I need a clean code, I don't care if it is complicated, I care mostly about accuracy and proper coding.

PS: if the `instanceof` the correct way, then would you please provide me with a small example on how to iterate the list with the different types.

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**: The different objects have no relation with each other, as in, they do not extend each other nor do they extend a super class. The blocks of each function are generating an SQLite statements which would be different for each type.

---

Respond to 'harsh's answer:

So I ended up using a combination of your suggestions, and that is to implement a base class with a function of `getClassType()` which returns a string of the class name, then I would check the returned value in the `update(List<T> list)` function.

```
public static <T extends Item> int update(List<T> list){
    ...
    // Loop through the list and call the update function
    for (T item: list){
        if (item.getClassType() == MyClass.CLASS_TYPE)
            update((MyClass) item);

    }
    ...
}

public interface Item {
    /**
     * @return Return the class type, which is the name of the class
     */
    public String getClassType();
}

public class ClassProject implements Item{
    public static final String CLASS_TYPE = "ClassProject";
    @Override
    public String getClassType() {
        return CLASS_TYPE;
    }
    ...
}

public class ClassTime implements Item{
    public static final String CLASS_TYPE = "ClassTime";
    @Override
    public String getClassType() {
        return CLASS_TYPE;
    }
    ...
}

public class MyClass implements Item{
    public static final String CLASS_TYPE = "MyClass";
    @Override
    public String getClassType() {
        return CLASS_TYPE;
    }
    ...
}
```

Reason for doing this whole `interface` is because I don't like `istanceof` and not sure about it's performance and cost, so I attempted to make one of my own. Now is this a terrible way of doing this?

Comment: What's happening in the processing blocks of the different types?  Does the code change if its a list if type A vs a list of type B or is the code generic and regardless of the underlying type in the list. The answer to this will decide one if two possible approaches.

Comment: it would be completely different based on the type. The code is to be creating an SQLite update statements for each item in the list and different for each type of item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you do something like this:

```
public class Update<T>
{

public static int update(List<T> objects){};

}
```

OR

```
public static <T> int update(List<T> objects){};
```

whichever is more appropriate in your case.

So if you go by second approach and due to type erasure at runtime, you are left with instanceof checking:

```
public static <T> int update(List<T> objects){
        for(T object : objects)
        {
            if(object.getClass().isInstance(Pair.class))
            {
                //do something
            }else if(object.getClass().isInstance(Time.class))
            {

            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

But that's doesn't look a good design, you can improve above by using a factory method:

```
    static Handler getHandler(Class<?> handlerClass)
        {
            if(handlerClass.isInstance(Project.class))
            {
                //return ProjectHandler
            }else if(handlerClass.isInstance(Time.class))
            {
                //return TimeHandler
            }
            //return errorHandler
        }
        interface Handler {
            int handle();
        }
       public static <T> int update(List<T> objects){
            for(T object : objects)
            {
                getHandler(object.getClass()).handle();
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Now a nicer approach IMO would be to designate your classes under update via marker interface and then cleanly handle update in each of the classes:

```
    interface Updateable {
        int update();
    }

    public static <T extends Updateable> int update2(List<T> objects){
        for(T object : objects)
        {
            object.update();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The first, that means different classes for each function right? if yes, then I can't do that, all functions need to be inside the same class. As for the second, I am assuming I would then be using `instanceof` right? Is that the right and efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Hey, I added a modification to my original question with the response, many thanks, and please tell me if it is a good way for dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answer to my comment you are left with two approaches. The first would be to try to come up with an interface that all the possible types that would be passed to this method implement. If your interface was called Foo you could define the method as something like:

```
public int update(List<Foo> list)
```

Then your code inside would be based on the methods available in Foo.

If you can't do this then you will need separate methods per possible type. You can't do instanceof at runtime due to Type Erasure. The underlying type if the list is erased in the compiled code and therefor will not be available for instanceof logic.

EDIT:
To clear up a little confusion on my above answer.  You can do `instanceof` on a per element basis when iterating the list, something like this:

```
for(Object item:list){
  if (item instanceof A){
    //do A based logic
  }
  else if (item instanceof B){
    //do B based logic
  }
}
```

You can't however check the list type at runtime like so:

```
if (list instanceof List<A>)
```

Your best bet really would be to try and generalize the types supported via an interface as suggested in my first solution.  Doing the instanceof approach will lead to code that will constantly need to be modified as you add more supported types.

Comment: Thanks :) but harsh presented his answer before you, so I checked his to be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding harsh's answer, can't you do:

```
public class Update
{

public static <T> int update(List<T> objects, Class<T> clazz){};

}
```

And then, in your implementation, vary behavior according to the passed Class instance?